# Using LESS js in rendering CSS for AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, less

I'm building an AngularJS directive, and I would like it to have it's own CSS file generated by LESS js. I cannot generate the file using LESS on the server side, only client for now. What I did is putting the code that brings LESS script and my stylesheet in the app.run module - code below.

The problem is, that the directive's template is loading before LESS has finished rendering the CSS file, so in this portion of time (not much, but enough) you can see the raw and ugly directive's template.

I tried:

1. ng-cloak on the template
2. Trying to figure out which event is firing when LESS finishes and delay the execution until then. But I didn't find the event, and I also didn't find how to delay the template showing.
3. Injecting `$document` to the directive and looking for my generated stylesheet there as an indicator that the CSS has been generated.

This is what I have for now:

```
angular.module('angularTablesorter', [])
.run(function($document) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet/less';
        link.href = 'css/myStyleSheet.less';
        $document[0].head.appendChild(link);

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'js/less.min.js';
        $document[0].head.appendChild(script);



})
.directive('ngTablesorter', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            /*Directive code goes here*/
        }
    };
}]);
```

Is what I am trying to do is even possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `visibility: hidden;` in a style that loads before the `less` style (can even be inline using `<style>`, and then override it in the `less` style.